# Connection Error in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

I am geeting this error whenever i am using the below command in ubuntu:
ssh localhost

it shows the error unable to connect to local host at port 22:connection refused

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Do an `ifconfig` and check that Local Loopback is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that you don't have sshd running, or it could be a misconfigured firewall (yes, you can firewall off localhost).

Comment: how can i turn on sshd ..plz help i am very new to linux environment??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have start server sshd.

`ps aux | grep sshd`  to check it

Comment: how to turn on sshd ? plz help on this

Answer (score 0):

You need a `ssh` server. Read the [community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH) on it for Ubuntu (it's short).

Install it via Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

And try connecting:

```
ssh localhost
```